# Need help deciding on a model for estimating births

Tags: r, regression, binary-data, multinomial-distribution

I'm working on a regression that predicts the number of births a female will have based on roughly ~15 variables. Therefore I have a discrete dependent variable. I was doing some research and it seems unfavorable to use a linear model for this estimation, so I then turned to a logit model. If I use the logit model I cannot predicts number of births, instead I can only get a probability of whether they will have a child or not. I was reading about multinomial regressions, but with the number of variables I have this could get extremely cumbersome very quickly, I tested it with only 2 variables, age and church attendance and my output was extremely long. I didn't see any significance levels either. I also ran into problems when I added all my variables,

```
Error in nnet.default(X, Y, w, mask = mask, size = 0, skip = TRUE, softmax = TRUE,  : too many (1044) weights
```

I don't know how to adjust the weights in R, I tried but I kept getting errors.

So what do you think would be the best course of action? The simpler logit model or the multinomial model? My lack of knowledge with the multinom is making we lean toward the former option.

Answer (score 0):

The natural model for this would be the [ordered logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit) or [ordered probit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_probit) model. I am sure R has standard functions to solve for these.